# Selecting data from one table based on the value of another

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**Subjects Table:**

```
id | account_id | name
-------------------------
 8 |    112     | Biology
```

**Topic Table:**

```
id | subject_id | name
-------------------------
 1 |     8      | Plants
```

Using Flask-SQLAlchemy, I would like to select a row from the `Topics` table based on the value of the `account_id` in the `Subjects` table.

I have a list of `account_id`'s like so: `users = [139, 193, 112, 028,]` and would like to select the topics of these users.

I tried this:

```
topicQuery = db.session.query(Topic).filter(Topic.Subject.has(Topic.Subject.accountID.in_(usersID))).all()
```

but received an error `AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Topic.Subject has an attribute 'accountID'`

I assumed this was an issue with how I defined my `Models.py` file which looks like so:

```
class Subject(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'subjects'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    accountID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accounts.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    Topic = db.relationship('Topic', backref=backref('Subject', cascade='delete'))

    def __init__(self, accountID, name):
        self.accountID = accountID
        self.name = name


class Topic(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'topics'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subjectID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subjects.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(150))

    def __init__(self, subjectID, name):
        self.subjectID = subjectID
        self.name = name
```

So why I do get this error and how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What does `print(028)` do in your version of python? I assume it should produce an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the extra `Topic.` from `Topic.Subject.accountID.in_(usersID)`:

```
topicQuery = (
    db.session.query(Topic)
    .filter(Topic.Subject.has(Subject.accountID.in_(usersID)))
    .all()
)
```

Or, do a simple join query, which is more than enough (and probably faster):

```
topicQuery = (
    db.session.query(Topic)
    .join(Subject).filter(Subject.accountID.in_(usersID))
    .all()
)
```